# laravel : Redirect customer and vendors to different pages after registration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

my problem is I have two types of users,customer and vendor and wants to redirect them after registration to specific page like customer dashboard or vendor dashboard, this is working fine with me on login but want this to work on registeration, as you know there is redirect code for one page in register controller

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

**login controller**

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
$this->validate($request,[
'email'=>'required|email',
'password'=>'required|min:6',
]);
if(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1,'role_id'=>2],$request->remember)){

return redirect()->intended(route('customer.dashboard'));

}elseif(Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['email'=>$request->email,'password'=>$request->password,'active'=>1,'role_id'=>1],$request->remember))
    {return redirect()->intended(route('vendor.dashboard'));

}return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
}
```

Comment: something is odd here, how does you know if a user is admin or just a user on registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a **redirectTo()** method in your register controller:

```
public function redirectTo() {
  if ($this->guard()->user()->role_id == 2) {
     return route('customer.dashboard');
  } elseif ($this->guard()->user()->role_id == 1) {
     return route('vendor.dashboard');
  }
}
```